# Does DaaS stands for Desktop as a Service or Data as a Service?

Tags: cloud-computing

I've seen some topics around DaaS on the web.

Some of them state that DaaS stands for Desktop as a Service, which basically is the offering of virtual desktops.

In the other hand, some topics state that DaaS stands for Data as a Service, which basically means the offering of a cloud to deliver data integration, data analytics, etc.. (to me, this is strange, because it's just like a combination of PaaS and SaaS - a well known combination in the market).

What does DaaS stands for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does DaaS stands for?

It stands for whatever the person using that term says it stands for.